# objdump of binary with debug info produces mangled output

Tags: c, debugging, objdump

I often notice severely mangled output with mixed assembly and C instructions in the output of `objdump -S`. This seems to happen only for binaries built with debug info. Is there any way to fix this?

To illustrate the issue i have written a simple program :

```
/* test.c */
#include <stdio.h>
int main()
{
        static int i = 0;    
        while(i < 0x1000000) {
                i++;
        }
        return 0;
}
```

The above program was built with/without debug info as follows :

```
$ gcc test.c -o test-release
$ gcc test.c -g -o test-debug
```

Disassembling the test-release binary works fine.
`$ objdump -S test-release`
produces the following clear and concise snippet for the `main()` function.

```
 080483b4 <main>:
 80483b4:       55                      push   %ebp
 80483b5:       89 e5                   mov    %esp,%ebp
 80483b7:       eb 0d                   jmp    80483c6 <main+0x12>
 80483b9:       a1 18 a0 04 08          mov    0x804a018,%eax
 80483be:       83 c0 01                add    $0x1,%eax
 80483c1:       a3 18 a0 04 08          mov    %eax,0x804a018
 80483c6:       a1 18 a0 04 08          mov    0x804a018,%eax
 80483cb:       3d ff ff ff 00          cmp    $0xffffff,%eax
 80483d0:       7e e7                   jle    80483b9 <main+0x5>
 80483d2:       b8 00 00 00 00          mov    $0x0,%eax
 80483d7:       5d                      pop    %ebp
 80483d8:       c3                      ret
```

But `$ objdump -S test-debug`
produces the following mangled snippet for the same `main()` function.

```
080483b4 <main>:
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
 80483b4:       55                      push   %ebp
 80483b5:       89 e5                   mov    %esp,%ebp

        static int i = 0;

        while(i < 0x1000000) {
 80483b7:       eb 0d                   jmp    80483c6 <main+0x12>
                i++;
 80483b9:       a1 18 a0 04 08          mov    0x804a018,%eax
 80483be:       83 c0 01                add    $0x1,%eax
 80483c1:       a3 18 a0 04 08          mov    %eax,0x804a018
int main()
{

        static int i = 0;

        while(i < 0x1000000) {
 80483c6:       a1 18 a0 04 08          mov    0x804a018,%eax
 80483cb:       3d ff ff ff 00          cmp    $0xffffff,%eax
 80483d0:       7e e7                   jle    80483b9 <main+0x5>
                i++;
        }   

        return 0;
 80483d2:       b8 00 00 00 00          mov    $0x0,%eax

}
 80483d7:       5d                      pop    %ebp
 80483d8:       c3                      ret
```

I do understand that as the debug binary contains additional symbol info, the C code is displayed interlaced with the assembly instructions. But this makes it a tad difficult to follow the flow of code.

> Is there any way to instruct **objdump** to output pure assembly and not interlace debug symbols into the output even if encountered in a binary?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use -d instead of -S. objdump is doing exactly what you are telling it to. The -S option implies -d but also displays the C source if debugging information is available.